# Separate Total count into M & F

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to separate the total count into - Male and Female.

So currently I have ,

```
City     TotalCount
Dubai     300
America   500
```

I want to make it look like :-

```
City      Male    Female
Dubai     150      150
America   250      250
```

My database has a sex column which has the Value M and F

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT service_area_name as City,
       count(DISTINCT booking.user_passenger_id) ,
       count(DISTINCT case when user.gender = 'M' then booking.user_passenger_id end) as males,
       count(DISTINCT case when user.gender = 'F' then booking.user_passenger_id end) as females
```

Comment: This gives me a desired result set, but when I add the sum of M & F , it is more than the total.

Comment: What do you mean "more than the total"?  In any given row, the sum of the males and females should be at most the total passengers -- unless a single passenger can have multiple genders.

Answer (score 0):

```
select service_area_name as City, sum(sex = 'M') as Male, sum(sex = 'F') as Female 
...etc.
```